# How to convert jar into war in kumuluz ee framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

I have multiple individual jar files web application and want to change into war file in order to deploy in java enterprise container like jboss, glassfish, websphere, etc. I can only run it as standalone application, need to deploy in java EE container.

I am using a kumuluz EE microframework.

Visit https://github.com/tfaga/KumuluzEE

Comment: if it's a maven project you can set the packaging tag in your pom.xml :  <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: Pom packaging as war doesn't work for this framework. It is similar to Spring Boot. Both of these frameworks start from command-line like stand alone application. Spring Boot do have war packing facility but this doesn't have. So, I want to know, if there is a way out like Spring Boot.

Comment: did you already tried this command line : jar cvf your_war_file.war,   as shown here http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-war-file-using-the-jar-command.html?page=1

Comment: I have tried it once, it doesn't work like you say. It has main method, just like standalone application, so the server actually start from main method entry point. Now, in order to start that one I have changed configuration in pom file too, but got an error while deploying it into Jboss EAP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the kumuluz-servlet and jetty part and add javaee-web-api.
And use the below dependency for building it.

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kumuluz.ee</groupId>
        <artifactId>kumuluzee-core</artifactId>
        <version>${kumuluzee.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kumuluz.ee</groupId>
        <artifactId>kumuluzee-jax-rs-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${kumuluzee.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>project_name</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.kumuluz.ee.EeApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And of course make packing as "war" file.